# Encryption in M language for Custom Data Connector

Tags: c#, powerbi, m, powerbi-datasource

Is there a way to encrypt this string in M language "bmVVNG46bmVB". Is it possible to call a C# function or something in M language or if M language has any libraries for standard encryptions like AES/DES

```
let
 Source = Web.Contents( "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
  [
    Headers = [#"Authorization" = "Basic bmVVNG46bmVB"]
  ]
in
 Source
```

Answer (score 0):

No. And encryption would be useless, since having tokens (passwords, OAuth tokens, etc) in an untrusted environment is not considered good practice.

You should implement a secure way of providing that value, for example through the password input field.

Comment: Yes there is password input box, however the username and password are sent as Basic Authentication, I want to atleast encrypt it further using some algorithm.

Comment: Authentication = [    
        UsernamePassword = []
           
    ],